# Asp.Net button has no ID in javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-4.0

I have some problems identifying an asp.net control in javascript. Here's a simple variant of my code, maybe you can see an error.

This function creates a set of button + label, it can be called multiple times:

```
    private void AddRow(Panel pnl)
    {
        var myButton = new Button();
        myButton.Text = "+";
        myButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return MyJavascript();");
        myButton.Attributes.Add("somevariable", "FOOBAR!");

        var lblAnzahl = new Label();

        pnl.Controls.Add(myButton);
        pnl.Controls.Add(lblAnzahl);
    }
```

This is the JS function the button calls:

```
            function MyJavascript(e) {
                var sender = event.target || event.srcElement;
                var somevar = sender.getAttribute("somevariable");
                alert('somevar: ' + somevar);
                alert('ID: ' + sender.id);
            }
```

The output is:

> somevar: FOOBAR!
>
> ID:

So I guess I get the correct sender, but for some reason the ID is always empty. The easiest way for me would be, if I could somehow set the ID of button and label myself, so that I can give it an unique ID every time AddRow() gets called, so I can easily identify the button and of course the label that belongs to the button.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check `sender.getAttribute("id")`

Comment: @RandRandom alert(sender.clientid) returns an 'undefined'

Comment: Need to create the client ID in a predictable way.
[MSDN Video](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/net-4/core/aspnet-4-quick-hit-predictable-client-ids)

Comment: Check clientid spelled correctly :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting an ID in your AddRow function.

Change your function to this:

```
private void AddRow(Panel pnl, int index)
{
    var myButton = new Button();
    myButton.ID = "button_" + index; // add this line (the index will guarantee a distinct ID)
    myButton.Text = "+";
    myButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return MyJavascript();");
    myButton.Attributes.Add("somevariable", "FOOBAR!");

    var lblAnzahl = new Label();

    pnl.Controls.Add(myButton);
    pnl.Controls.Add(lblAnzahl);
}
```

You can invoke the code like this:

```
AddRow(pnl, 0);
AddRow(pnl, 1);
AddRow(pnl, 2);
```

Comment: Ah, ok... ID in asp.net = ClientID in javascript. Thanks, that helped. :)

Comment: Hum, not quite... Javascript, as a standalone language, does not know about ClientID's.  The ClientID terminology is only used in asp.net. The thing is, in asp.net you can't set the ClientID to a control, you have to set the ID value instead. This in turn will make the asp.net framework generate a proper ClientID, which you can then reference from javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `myButton.ClientID` or add name attribute `myButton.Attributes.Add("name", "FOOBAR");` with check to be sure that name is unique and retrieve in Javascript by getElementByName

Comment: myButton.ClientID is readyonly and doesn't return anything either. I've also tried var mybutton = document.getElementsByName("FOOBAR")[0], but then mybutton is undefined.